# 100% width messing up with the padding

Tags: html, css, padding

In the `.SalesPanel` class, I have set it to 100% width. I have notice its over-lapping the padding on the right that I have set in `content` id.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/CBAE7/9/ and look at the right padding and compare it with left padding.

What causing this and how to fix?

Also I was expecting 3 div's on 1 row even using 100% width.. how to fix?

**HTML:**

```
<div id='content'>
  <div class='SalesPanel'> One </div>
  <div class='SalesPanel'> Two </div>
  <div class='SalesPanel'> Three </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#content {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #C8CCD5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.SalesPanel {
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
  width: 100%
}
​
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't reflect your code.

Comment: I have added a screenshot so you can see what I meant

Comment: Right, the Fiddle you list in your post is an incorrect link.  http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CBAE7/6 is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CBAE7/11/)**.

```
#content {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #C8CCD5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.SalesPanel {
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  height:30px;
  width: 33%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0;
}​
```

Comment: No, I do I need `float` because I am going to add more div's

Comment: Maybe a better example in your question that shows the final goal would be helpful.

Comment: Oh ok you use `width: 33%;` - The thing is I might have more than 3 divs or less.. I want all to fit in one row.. hmmm

Comment: Well if you know the number of divs then you can easily calculate the percentage. If they'll vary that's a different issue (and again you may want to note this in your original question).

Answer (score 2):

Change [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property:

```
.SalesPanel {
  /* your stuff */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Initial value of `box-sizing` for modern browsers is `content-box`. It means that `width: 100%` will affect only the content, not counting padding and borders (your case). By changing this property to `box-sizing` you will fit it in the container. The actual width of the content will be [`calc(100% - 2px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc).

It's CSS 3 property and supported by IE 8+ and all other modern browsers.

Comment: Wow  that fixed a problem, I never heard of `box-sizing:` before.

Comment: You might want to mention that box-sizing is CSS3 and not available in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Also, seeing as you are using a static 3 of them, 33% width never hurt either.

```
.SalesPanel {
  border:1px solid #dddddd;
  height:30px;
  float:left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
.SalesPanel {
    border:1px solid #dddddd;
    height:30px;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```